# On the flow C parser

Tags: c, frameworks, parsing

I am looking for a dynamic C-based parser/framework.
It must be dynamic because the EBNF is constantly changing, something like bison is not applicable in this situation. And boost::spirit is practically useless to me because it requires C++.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: What's stopping you using boost::spirit with a wrapper to call it from C code?

Comment: "the EBNF is constantly changing" -- at run time?

Comment: just a curiosity: what is your task about? I treated BNFs just in my Compiler course at the University, so I'm wondering about a situation in which a BNF changes constantly

Comment: I hope they have an assignment like developing a language, and the BNF changes weekly or so, it's impossible to create operations to a changed semantic at runtime otherwise I would vote for turing award ;-)

Comment: it's a crude hack, but you could use something like [tinyCC](http://repo.or.cz/w/tinycc.git), [CINT](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/cint) or [Ch](http://www.softintegration.com/) to compile/interpret code emitted by one of the classical parser generators at runtime

Comment: @Anon

My code is making use of the reserved keywords in C++. To adapt, I would be breaking about 8 libraries that depend on the current code.

Comment: @Christoph

I am already exploring the "llvm"-alternative, but this alternative is very time-consuming. So I wondered if there was something available that avoids such tactics...

Comment: @Flaps: the problem with LLVM is that though the resulting code is fast, compilation isn't; as you expect to re-compile often, one of the alternatives I mentioned might be preferable; I'm quite fond of tinyCC, but it's far from bug-free

Answer (score 0):

If you want the grammar to change while the computation is running, then what you want is an [Earley-style context free parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earley_parser).  You can change the rules at any time and run the Earley parsing algorithm.

If the grammar changes "slowly" (e.g., once a day), then you don't need a dynamically-augmentable parser like Earley; you can use conventional parser generators and simply run them as needed.

Comment: Sorry for assuming that the BNF changes after review by professor, at least I learned that I'm not up to date wth this.

Comment: That could be the way to go.
I will certainly explore this algorithm. Thank you!